# Three Monitors with Nvidia GeForce 9500

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

I have the following Nvidia GeForce 9500 video card (2 DVI connections, 1 S-Video):

[image]

I run Linux Mint 11 and can either use open source or Nvidia drivers without any problems. I'm using 1020x768 as the resolution for each monitor. The monitors I'd like to use all have VGA and DVI connectors and I currently have two working without any problems.

Is there any way I can split one of the DVI connectors or convert the S-video into a DVI/VGA for a third monitor? If not, what hardware do I need to add a third monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May have to dig up the user manual on this one.  I had a Nvidia quadro and it only supported up to 2 monitors at one time.  The only way you maybe able to do a 3 monitor setup would be to go SLI or find a card that explicitly supports 3 monitors.